# What is the alternative in harmony OS for Matrix.MTRANS_X or Matrix.MSCALE_X enums in android?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

In Android for Matrix few enums are predefined such as *MSCALE_X, MSCALE_Y, MTRANS_X, MTRANS_Y, MSCEW_X, MSCEW_Y*. Do we have any  such alternatives in Harmony OS?

Comment: Is HarmonyOS just a rename of constants, enumerations, and functions?

Answer (score 0):

As Harmony OS rewrites some functionalities/API's in a completely new way from Scratch, you may not have exact API's available in Android. For those functionalities , try extending Harmony API's and write custom behavior of required API.

For your Case extend **ohos.agp.utils.Matrix** API substitute those predefined Enum's.